# Cardano - cardano-cli query utxo - get all utxo of an address

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

As the title, I've been wondering if `cardano-cli` has an ability to get all utxo based on given address.

I already tried

```
cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat /path/to/addr) --testnet-magic 1097911063 --whole-utxo
```

But, it will return an error message

```
Invalid option '--whole-utxo'
```

I'm kinda confuse as on `help` it says, that `--whole-utxo` is available, but I do notice, that, it's like an option we choose between `--whole-utxo` or `--address` or `--tx-in`.

---

I tried to dig some documents / forum and even on official github, but I found no clue to do so.

Mostly it pointed to install `db-sync` etc, but, tbh, I'm not a fan to install or use other additional components outside cardano-cli (`db-sync`, `blockfrost`, etc).

I prefer to use the `core` itself rather than rely on `outside of core`.

Been wonder if I missed something.

Thanks & Cheers.

Comment: for the case you want to give an address instead of path of file of your wallet, and also you want to have output of a wallet in mainnet, please find below. cardano-cli query utxo --address addr1q898ttf4nk6u6qfdlgfkh4985740sdfghsgtlykxhjsd9y48u03pzezspr2drk --mainnet please replace the address with the one you want to see all the current UTXOs

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies & sorry for late comments. I already try that way and as far as I notice, it only return with `last utxo` not `whole / all utxo` that occurred on that given address.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it via cli omitting --whole-utxo

```
cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat /path/to/addr) --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies & sorry for late comments. I already done that way, but as far as I notice, it only give `last utxo` not `whole / all utxo` that occurred on that given address

Comment: Oh i see. I think cardano node or cli doesn't have this feature as far as I know we have to use dbsync or blockfrost for the same.

Comment: Ahh I see! seems yes, I've been search around and didn't found it. Thanks anyway for your replies & references! :)